# Using Devise in RoR - How to have only a few pages not require login - Override authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

For the majority of my site, I want to require login.  But for two pages, I need to have a user be able to submit to the page without logging in.

Is there a way to override the

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

which I put in the application controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your desired controller, add:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:some_action, :another_action]
```

Read more about filters at [Module ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Yep, this is what I did.  Should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:action_name_1, :action_name_2]
```